# Showing in a normed vector space $(V, \| \cdot \|)$ we have $B_{r}(\vec{x}) = \vec{x} + B_{r}(\vec{0}) := \{\vec{x}+\vec{y} : \|\vec{y}\| < r \}$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, solution-verification, normed-spaces

I just recently worked out that in a normed vector space $(V, \| \cdot \|)$ we have $$B_{r}(\vec{x}) : = \{\vec{y} \in V : \|\vec{x} - \vec{y}\| < r \}  = \vec{x} + B_{r}(\vec{0}) := \{\vec{x}+\vec{y} : \|\vec{y}\| < r \}.$$ I believe I have shown the first inclusion $B_{r}(\vec{x}) \subseteq \vec{x} + B_{r}(\vec{0})$ , but I am unsure if my work is completely correct. As well, I have also been having trouble showing the second inclusion $\vec{x} + B_{r}(\vec{\vec{0}}) \subseteq B_{r}(\vec{x})$. Here is my work so far:

---

Know that $d(\vec{x},\vec{y}) := d_{\| \cdot \|} = \|\vec{x} - \vec{y}\|$ (the norm induced standard metric),

$\bullet$ First, show that $B_{r}(\vec{x}) \subseteq \vec{x} + B_{r}(\vec{0})$.

Let $\vec{y} \in B_{r}(\vec{x})$, we want to show that $\vec{y} \in \vec{x}+B_{r}(\vec{0})$. Therefore, since  $\vec{y} \in B_{r}(\vec{x})$
$$\begin{align*} &\implies \|\vec{x} - \vec{y}\| < r \\ &\implies \|-\vec{y} + \vec{x}\| < r \\ &\implies \|-1\cdot (\vec{y}-\vec{x})\| < r \\ &\implies |-1| \cdot \|\vec{y}-\vec{x}\| < r \\ &\implies \|\vec{y} - \vec{x}\| < r \end{align*}$$ and since $\vec{x} \in V$, $\vec{x}$ is arbitrary so $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$ and therefore: $$\begin{align*} \\ &\implies \|\vec{y} - \vec{0}\| < r \\ &\implies \|\vec{y}\| < r \end{align*} . $$ so $\vec{y} \in  \vec{x}+B_{r}(\vec{0})$.

**Remarks**: Where I am unsure in my work is if saying "since $\vec{x} \in V$, $\vec{x}$ is arbitrary so $\vec{x} = \vec{0}$" is correct or not. Everything else seems fine to me, however, any criticism is welcome.

$\bullet$ Second, show that $\vec{x} + B_{r}({\vec{0}}) \subseteq B_{r}(\vec{x})$. It may be helpful to keep in mind that $B_r(\vec{0}) : = \{\vec{y} \in V : \|\vec{y}\| < r \}$.

Let $\vec{x} + \vec{y} \in \vec{x} + B_{r}({\vec{0}})$. We want to show that $\vec{x} + \vec{y} \in B_{r}(\vec{x})$. Since $\vec{x} + \vec{y} \in \vec{x} + B_{r}({\vec{0}})$ $$\begin{align*} \\ &\implies \|\vec{y}\| < r \\ &\implies \vec{y} \in B_r(\vec{0}) \\ &\implies ... \end{align*}$$

This is where I have gotten stuck, but I have some thoughts: Is it true that $B_r(\vec{0}) \subseteq B_r(\vec{x})$? I was thinking that if that is true, then we can use that to somehow arrive at that $||\vec{x} - \vec{y}|| < r$ (the definition of $B_r(\vec{x})$) from $\|\vec{y}|| < r$. Again any hints, criticism, etc. is welcome.

Comment: how do you define $B_r(x)$ ? I guess it's $\{y\mid \|x-y\|<r\}$, so the answer is straighforward...

Comment: @Surb - I defined it exactly like that in my introduction of the question. Also, straightforward in what way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $y \in B_r (x) $, we have $\vert \vert y-x \vert \vert < r $, this means that $y-x \in B_r (0)$, and you can write $y=x+(y-x),$ which solves the first inclusion.

For the second inclusion, take $y=x+v$ with $\vert \vert v \vert \vert \in B_r (0)$, then $v=y-x$, with $\vert \vert y-x \vert \vert = \vert \vert v \vert \vert <r$, and this means that $y\in B_r(x) $.